# When per unit indirect tax is imposed on a good does the supply curve shift left or does it shift upwards?

Tags: supply-and-demand, taxation

My economics textbook says it shifts upwards but my school notes tell me it shifts leftwards. So which one is true? Or are they both true?

Comment: This answer might help: https://qr.ae/pG0F9y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that without the tax, supply is given by $Q(P)$ or $P(Q)$, while with the tax, it is $Q^t(P)$ or $P^t(Q)$. Since the tax is a fixed amount per unit, producers don't care whether the market price is $P-t$ and there is no tax imposed, or the market price is $P$ and there is a tax of $t$. Thus, $Q(P-t)=Q^t(P)$. In terms of inverse supply, this means $P^t(Q)=P(Q)+t$. Since price is on the vertical axis, this corresponds to an upwards *parallel shift* of the supply curve.

The confusion often arises because supply curves in introductory textbooks are usually depicted as linear. For linear supply curves, however, parallel left shifts cannot be distinguished visually (or by any other means) from parallel upwards shifts---they are indeed equivalent.

Another source of confusion is that some treat the term "shift" in a somewhat loose manner. If a shift is not necessarily meant to be a *parallel* shift, but rather just a dislocation which moves all points of a curve in the same direction by *some* amount, then an upwards shift and a left shift of a supply curve are actually the same thing (and the same holds for an upwards shift and a right shift of a demand curve).

Summarizing, depending on how you interpret the term "shift", either both your textbook and your notes are correct, or your notes are wrong.